# How to solve an ODBC/OLE-DB error in power BI?

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I am having trouble in power bi and bigquery data connection.

I am getting the following error:

```
error retured -OLE-DB or ODBC error.
unable to authenticate with bigquery storage API.
check your account permission.
```

Comment: I find `check your account permission` message quite enlightening.

Comment: You can check API endpoint and user permission. If it still continues same error, look at the OLDB setup in the client.